# Crosswalk's XWalkView (an alternative to Webview) not working with AppBarLayout + CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, webview, android-scrollview, crosswalk-runtime, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm trying to achieve the scrolling `Toolbar` technique (hiding `Toolbar` when scrolling down in a sibling child view) using `CoordinatorLayout` and `AppBarLayout`.

I'm using [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/)'s [XWalkView](https://crosswalk-project.org/apis/embeddingapidocs_v5/index.html) (it's a view which functions like WebView).

When using regular [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) (inside a `NestedScrollView`) I can achieve the wanted effect:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webViewOrig"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

However when using the `XWalkView` in the same way, I can't get it to work.
After using the following XML layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport = "true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <org.xwalk.core.XWalkView
            android:id="@+id/webViewCross"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

the view doesn't even appear.

When removing the following line

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

the `XWalkView` is at least displayed but on the whole screen and on top of the Toolbar.

What should I do to make it work? Since it's an open-source I should be able to make it work... I suspect it's either subclass `XWalkView` and implement some interface (`NestedScrollingChild`?) or creating a custom behaviour by subclassing `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` or `AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior`.

Any ideas?

BTW `XWalkView` is using internally either [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) or [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) to render the web content.

Comment: i have the same issue, do you have figured it out?

Comment: @LucaLooz Did you find a solution ?